# Sorting in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, shell

I have been trying to get the unique values in each column of a tab delimited file in bash. So, I used the following command.

```
cut -f <column_number> <filename> | sort | uniq -c
```

It works fine and I can get the unique values in a column and its count like

```
105 Linux
55  MacOS
500 Windows
```

What I want to do is instead of sorting by the column value names (which in this example are OS names) I want to sort them by count and possibly have the count in the second column in this output format. So It will have to look like:

```
Windows 500
MacOS   105
Linux   55
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use (where `N` is the column number and `F` is the input file):

```bash
cut -f N F |sort |uniq -c |sort -nrk1,1 |awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

The initial `sort/uniq` is to get each OS in the form `<count> <os>` so that the rest of the pipeline can work on it.

The `sort -nrk1,1` sorts numerically (`n`), in reverse order (`r`), using the first field (`-k1,1`).

The `awk` then simply reverses the order of the columns. You can test the full pipeline with the following:

```bash
pax> cat test.in
a   Windows
b   Linux
c   Windows
d   Windows
e   Linux
f   Windows
g   MacOS
h   Linux
i   Windows
j   MacOS
k   Windows
l   Linux
m   MacOS
n   Windows
o   Linux
p   MacOS
q   Windows
r   Linux
s   Linux
t   Linux
u   Linux
v   Linux

pax> cut -f2 test.in |sort |uniq -c |sort -nrk1,2 |awk '{print $2" "$1}'
Linux 10
Windows 8
MacOS 4
```

This test file format is *similar* in style to your own input, including tabs separating the fields. It's unlikely to be the *exact* same format so you'll need to tailor the `cut` command to your own file, in such a way that it only gives you the desired column.

However, you've probably already done that since that's not the bit you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Mine:

```
cut -f <column_number> <filename> | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2" "$1}' | sort
```

This will alter the column order (awk) and then just sort the output.

Hope this will help you

Comment: That sorts by name rather than count.

Comment: Sure, from sfactor question: "What I want to do is instead of sorting by the column value names"

Answer (score 0):

Using sed based on Tagged RE:

```
cut -f <column_number> <filename> | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -k1 -n | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)[ ]*\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

Doesn't produce output in a neat format though.